# What is the major difference between freeglut and glut

Tags: opengl

i started programming with glut and i have been reading posts about freeglut bettering glut
which is better and why?

Answer (score 4):

The original implementation of GLUT was released under a license that prohibited modification.  freeglut is a reimplementation of the GLUT API under a MIT license. There has been more development on freeglut and it has extensions to the API as well, but in my experience, there are some quirks of older versions of GLUT that aren't replicated in freeglut.  However, if you just start using glut, you might as well use freeglut.

But, I wouldn't recommend using GLUT or freeglut for window management in the first place.  You'll be much better off in the long run using something like wxWindows or QT.